# Throwing an error outside of promise flow

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

I have a method that calls a promised function. Before I call this method, however, I need to perform some validation.

```
var outerMethod = function(params) {
  if(!params) throw new Error();

  return somePromiseFunction();
}
```

What is the proper way to throw the first error. I have tried wrapping the entire outerMethod inner content in a `new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { });` but that did not quite do the trick;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could answer a rejected promise, like this:

```
var outerMethod = function(params) {
    return (!params)? q.defer().reject(new Error('missing params')) : somePromiseFunction();
}
```

Style-wise, I'd reverse the condition `(params)? /* happy case */ : /* sad case */;`, but I left it in the negative since we're talking about the rejection.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to do that with Bluebird in a streamlined way?

Comment: @Yashua Returning `Promise.reject(new Error(...))` is probably the cleanest way.